# Update docker on Debian 10

Tags: docker, ubuntu, debian, apt

I try to update docker on Debian, with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change
```

But I got the following error message:

```
Hit:1 http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/debian buster-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Get:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster InRelease [54.0 kB]
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Ign:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu docker InRelease
Err:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu docker Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.224.94.87 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu docker Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

From another StackOverflow topic, it seems I must update the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

I tried the following (but it does not work):

```
deb https://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main
```

Noticed that:

- I use Debian 10
- The following command print "buster" : https://download.docker.com/linux/debian

Should I change to something like, without corrupting/breaking my operating system?

```
deb https://download.docker.com/linux/debian docker buster
```

Comment: The source url is not okay. I dunno exactly how.

Comment: @peterh Indeed, but I the last url (download.docker.com) seems correct. I just don't know what I must put after. Zesty or buster, I do not really understand what it mean... I do not want to break my operating system. You see?

Comment: Docker is written in go, thus it is very distro-independent. Probably even a redhat docker could run on a debian distro. Furthermore, all the linux distros are smart enough: if you install something what you should have not, and then uninstall it, 99.999999% that nothing will happen. That is my sources.list URL for a debian bullseye: `deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian   bullseye stable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Install Docker Engine on Debian](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/). Use the following commands:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg

echo \
"deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable" |\
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

The first command will download the gpg key, the second one will adjust your docker.list file.

Then run `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 1):

Create the following file:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list 
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable
```

Then remove any other `download.docker.com` entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on a VM once. The repo for "https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu docker" does not exist and needs to be removed. Unsure why it's there.

This worked for me:

1. open the source list (providing there isn't external source lists):

   `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. remove any lines for "ubuntu" as you are on Debian 10 and save
3. run `sudo apt-get update`